# IBM's CPLEX cplex.setOut(env.getNullStream()) not working properly

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

I've already looked through the questions to see if anybody has already asked this, and to my knowledge no one else has had this problem.

I'm trying to suppress the verbose output of oplrun from the command line. I know that some people have had luck using cplex.setOut(env.getNullStream()), where cplex is an object of type IloCplex. The function setOut() is inherited from the IloAlgorithm class.

When I try to use this in my main code block within my model (.mod) file, I get the error:

Scripting runtime error: unknown property 'setOut'.

I'm placing the function call before my call to solve().

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks.

Here is a code snippet:

```
main{

    var opl = thisOplModel;
    var mod = opl.modelDefinition;
    var dat = opl.dataElements;
    var set = opl.settings;
    var cplex1 = new IloCplex();

    cplex1.setOut(env.getNullStream()); //Giving me problems

    opl = new IloOplModel(mod,cplex1);
    opl.addDataSource(dat);
    opl.generate();

    cplex1.tilim = opl.tiLim;
    cplex1.mipemphasis = 0;

    cplex1.solve();
    // more stuff ... 
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code? If you only include the snippets where you create the `IloCplex` instance and where you call `setOut`, this could be helpful. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you're using [IBM ILOG Script for OPL](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.2/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/intro.html?pos=2) (aka oplscript). The `setOut` method is only available in the C++, Java, .NET OPL APIs (see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/classes/IloAlgorithm.html#method_setOut), for example).

According to [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/oplparams/topics/opl_params_mpoptions_cplexparams.html) page in the documentation, `CPX_PARAM_SCRIND` is one of the "CPLEX parameters with no equivalent OPL option". Unless you switch to using one of the C++, Java, or .NET OPL APIs, I don't think it will be possible to do what you're asking. A similar question was asked on the official IBM developerWorks forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=916aa0a4-b6e0-4d26-a24e-af19e534ff44).

Comment: Interesting. I definitely didn't make the connection. It's too bad that there is not a similar mechanism for suppressing the output, but oh well. Thanks.